# Showing a value periodicaly in a new column, based on another column value

Tags: sql-server, periodicity

I would like to have a query that based on the field "Periodicity", would repeat every N rows the value True, grouped by the field "Type". 
I think I can explain better with an example:

By having the next table...

```
id  type periodicity
1   1    3
2   1    3
3   1    3
4   1    3
5   1    3
6   1    3
7   1    3
8   1    3
9   1    3
10  2    2
11  2    2
12  2    2
13  2    2
14  2    2
15  2    2
16  2    2
```

... I would like to have a query that would return something like this...

```
id  type periodicity    execute_operation
1   1    3              TRUE
2   1    3              FALSE
3   1    3              FALSE
4   1    3              TRUE
5   1    3              FALSE
6   1    3              FALSE
7   1    3              TRUE
8   1    3              FALSE
9   1    3              FALSE
10  2    2              TRUE
11  2    2              FALSE
12  2    2              TRUE
13  2    2              FALSE
14  2    2              TRUE
15  2    2              FALSE
16  2    2              TRUE
```

For the rows where the field "type" is 1, the field "execute_operation" would be marked as True every 3 rows (the value defined in the field "periodicity").

For the rows having the "type"is 2, the filed "execute_operation" would be marked as True every 2 rows.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine the windowed function [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with the [modulo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190279.aspx) operator.

Row number sequences each group (1, 2, 3, ...).  Modulo returns the position within the sequence by calculating the remainder.  Example:

1 Mod 3 = 1.

2 Mod 3 = 2.

3 Mod 3 = 0.

When the mod of *row number* over *periodicity* is 1 then true is returned.

```
WITH [Sample] AS 
    (
        -- CTE provides sample data.
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            (
                VALUES
                    (1,  1, 3),
                    (2,  1, 3),
                    (3,  1, 3),
                    (4,  1, 3),
                    (5,  1, 3),
                    (6,  1, 3),
                    (7,  1, 3),
                    (8,  1, 3),
                    (9,  1, 3),
                    (10, 2, 2),
                    (11, 2, 2),
                    (12, 2, 2),
                    (13, 2, 2),
                    (14, 2, 2),
                    (15, 2, 2),
                    (16, 2, 2)
            ) AS x(id, [type], periodicity)
    )
SELECT
    s.id,
    s.[type],
    s.periodicity,
    CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  s.[type] ORDER BY s.id) % periodicity
        WHEN 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS execute_operation
FROM
    [Sample] AS s
ORDER BY
    s.id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done like below to achieve required result Instead of '%' (mod) you can keep periodicity. And i have assumed your id column will have sequentiall numbers so i have used it because of eliminating `row_number`

```
    SELECT ID,
       TYPE,
       CASE
         WHEN RNO = 1
              AND TYPE = 1 THEN 'TRUE'
         WHEN RNO = 2
              AND TYPE = 2 THEN 'TRUE'
         ELSE 'FALSE'
       END STATUS
FROM   (SELECT ID,
               TYPE,
               CASE
                 WHEN TYPE = 1 THEN Replace(ID%3, 0, 3)
                 ELSE Replace(ID%2, 0, 2)
               END RNO
        FROM   #TABLE1)A
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like below, please replace with the appropriate column names,

```
update tbl_Sample set Operation = 0 --default to false

;WITH CTE
AS
(
select *
,ROW_NUMBER() over(Partition by Periodicity order by ID) 'R'
 from tbl_Sample

 )

 UPDATE CTE
 SET Operation = 1
 WHERE R%Periodicity = 1
```